# How can I use a variable as a key to a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows:

```
var currency = "USD";
var value = 100;

function test(currency, value) {
    var myObject = {("" + currency): value};
    console.log(myObject);
}

test(currency, value);
```

I'm trying to get an object as follows:

```
{"USD": 100}
```

How do I fix my code to do this?

Comment: Use the `[ ]` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for the object.

```js
function test(currency, value) {
    return { [currency]: value };
}

var currency = "USD",
    value = 100;

console.log(test(currency, value));
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript we can add object with:

- dot notation
- square brackets

But only second case allows to access/add properties dynamically like this-

```js
var currency = "USD";
var value = 100;
var myObject = {};

function test(currency, value) {
  myObject[currency] = value;
  console.log(myObject);
}

test(currency, value);
```